# Passport OAuth2 Callback URL Fires Twice

Tags: node.js, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm using Passport OAuth2 to authenticate with an API that currently does not have a custom Passport Strategy. My issue seems to be that the first GET request with the access code to `/auth/moxtra/callback?code=<code here>` hangs and never seems to resolve, which then causes a second GET request to the same URL to fire. At this point though, the access code has already been invalidated by the API, which causes a server error, so the user never gets redirected back to my application. Here's the output:

```
GET /auth/moxtra/callback?code=v-cqK8ywP2I - - ms - -
GET /auth/moxtra/callback?code=v-cqK8ywP2I 500 665.180 ms - 1231
```

What's interesting is that I know the request works, since I'm logging the response I'm getting back; the desired resources that I'm querying for are successfully returned. But then the 500 server error blocks the redirect back to my application.

I'm not completely sure this is a Passport error, but I've been talking to the backend guy who manages the API and from his testing, he doesn't think it's an issue on his end.

I'd greatly appreciate any ideas/feedback!

EDIT: Here's the code for the OAuth strategy:

```
passport.use('moxtra', new OAuthStrategy({
  authorizationURL: 'https://api.moxtra.com/oauth/authorize',
  tokenURL: 'https://api.moxtra.com/oauth/token',
  clientID: configAuth.moxtraAuth.clientID,
  clientSecret: configAuth.moxtraAuth.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: configAuth.moxtraAuth.callbackURL
},
function(accessToken, done) {
  console.log("Access token: ", accessToken);
  var url = 'https://api.moxtra.com/me?access_token=' + accessToken;
  request.get(url, function(err, response, body) {
    if (!err && response.statusCode == 200) {
      console.log("Response body: ", body);
    }
  });
}));
```

And here's the route middleware code:

```
app.get('/auth/moxtra', passport.authenticate('moxtra'));

app.get('/auth/moxtra/callback', passport.authenticate('moxtra', {
  successRedirect : '/profile',
  failureRedirect : '/',
  failureFlash : true
}));
```

Currently I'm just logging the access token and response body to the console. Both are successfully returning. I have no idea what's causing the first GET request to not resolve.

Comment: The first issue you need to address is why the first request never resolves. Try putting console.log's after each async operation during your authentication process.

Comment: Can you show us some code?  Without that, we won't be able to help much.

Comment: You are not calling the `done` callback in the strategy callback. Call `done` in `request.get` callback.